# Removing .php from URL & Get Request

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get

By using `.htaccess` I have been able to turn the URL:
`http://www.websitename.co.uk/directory/users.php?id=idValue&data2=data2Value` 
Into
`http://www.websitename.co.uk/directory/users?id=idValue&data2=data2Value`

**HTAccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

However, I would much rather like to see it turned into this:
`http://www.websitename.co.uk/directory/users/idValue?data2=data2Value`

I hope that makes sense, for now just echoing the idValue is all I would need help with on the PHP side as I am unsure how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^directory/users/([0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ directory/users.php?id=$1&data2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: Is there a way to make this more scalable for different get requests and pages etc?

Comment: Yes, you can write custom router which will parse and resolve HTTP query. The algorithm is about such: 1. get http query 2.parse it 3.resolve to needed action.

Comment: Very wide theme) Example of attractive routing you can get in modern frameworks. [as Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing)